# CSV file for reading stock tickers

Tags: python, loops, csv

I am trying to read the names of two stock tickers, create a csv file in that contains the three columns, with a header row:
date stock1 stock2
containing the opening price for each stock on each of the previous 30 days of trading. The csv file should be named ‘stock1stock2date.csv’, where stock1 and stock2 are the names the user entered and date is today’s date.
So far I have:

```
import csv

with open('ticker1','ticker2', 'r') as csvfile:
    ticker1 = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    ticker2 = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')


def saveAsCsv(ticker1):
    filename = ticker1 + ticker2 + date + ".csv"
    for row in filename:
       #What goes here?

def stockInfo(ticker1):
    url1 = urllib.request.urlopen(
     'http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%s'%ticker1)
    t11Data = url1.readlines()

def main():
    ticker1 = input('Enter the first stock ticker.')
    ticker2 = input('Enter the second stock ticker.')
    date = input('Enter todays date.')
```

I am stuck on the for loop for creating the rows and columns. Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you stuck? What logic are you trying to implement?

Comment: to write to a new file use with open('output.out', 'w') as output_file

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
from pandas.io.data import get_data_yahoo

def main():
    ticker1 = input('Enter the first stock ticker.')
    ticker2 = input('Enter the second stock ticker.')
    data = get_data_yahoo([ticker1, ticker2])
    filename = ticker1 + ticker2 + str(datetime.date.today()) + ".csv"
    data.Open[-30:].to_csv(filename)
```